# sensor resolution impact on dynamics

Tags: matlab, dynamic, controls, sensors, floor

Is there a way to apply sensor model inside dynamics of a system in Matlab?

Suppose dynamics of open loop system are:

```
xdot = A x + B u
y = c x + D u
```

x is 4 states `(th1, th2, th1_dot, th2_dot)`. The open loop system is denoted by `G_p`, and the control is denoted by `G_c`. The closed loop system would be

```
G_cl = Gp Gc/(1+Gp*Gc)
```

For now, I model sensor with `floor` function in Matlab and after controlling the system and simulating the response of system to a given input, I quantize one of the states with floor function. But, since this does not give realistic impact of sensor on other states, I want to move sensor model inside my open loop dynamics or at least before the controller is implemented.

I appreciate any ideas.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This question does not have anything to do with electronics!

Comment: That is correct, but electronics.stackexchange.com is actually "Electrical Engineering SE" with an unfortunate url. And yes, it is an electrical engineering question, and no, it does definitely not belong here, as it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add additional transfer function or state-space system in your feedback loop to represent the system dynamics:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you explain what is sensor model in this block diagram? is it a transfer function? because I model sensor with floor function which is a nonlinear function and I do not know how to add it to my open loop state space model. @am304

Comment: It could be whatever you want... A transfer function with full dynamics or a simple `floor` function. The problem with nonlinear functions as you found out is you can't use traditional linear control design tools. If you have Simulink, your best option would be to implement this in a block diagram.

Comment: That's right. I have Matlab functions and scripts. Since the model is too complicated with optimization, it is implemented in Matlab as code, and I have simple pole placement control, I guess it is not possible to apply it this way then.